# Debugging error on Android emulator: black screen

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, emulation

I found a problem while I was trying to debug the next code:

```
package course.examples.theanswer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TheAnswer extends Activity {

public static final int[] answers = { 42, -10, 0, 100, 1000 };
public static final int answer = 42;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.answer_layout);

      TextView answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_view);

          int val = findAnswer();
      String output = (val == answer) ? "42" : "We may never know";
      answerView.setText("The answer to life, the universe and everything is:\n\n"
                    + output);
}

private int findAnswer() {
    for (int val : answers) {
        if (val == answer)
            return val;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

I have inserted a break-point in the line `"int val = findAnswer();"`, that is to say, before the app executes the message("The answer to life..."). So, the emulator shows the white screen with the title, it's right, but when it passes about 10 seconds the screen turns black... and the logCat shows the next message:

```
01-23 05:57:29.995: I/System.out(2009): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-23 05:57:30.205: I/System.out(2009): debugger has settled (1309)
01-23 05:57:30.845: D/dalvikvm(2009): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
01-23 05:57:37.825: W/ActivityManager(1254): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
01-23 05:57:37.835: E/WindowManager(1254): Starting window AppWindowToken{b33e2a00 token=Token{b3344b58 ActivityRecord{b317b130 u0 course.examples.theanswer/.TheAnswer t10}}} timed out
```

Tthe final message is when the screen turns black. I can't post images but the emulator only shows: hour, network and battery. Also, if I pressed "resumen" button, the app fihishes fine. However, I think that is not the idea. It should stop with the white screen to keep debugging...(I think, but I'm not sure). Is it normal?

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: what issue you have actually? Isn't your answer being displayed or what?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for editing my question. And yes, the answer is displayed but only if I pressed "resume" button. And I think that the app has to stop before showing the message due to break-point, hasn't it? Of course, it stops, but only for 10 seconds or so. Later, the screen turns black. And I think that the correct behaviour is that you can see what happens(although I know the app is fine) before the message.

Comment: forget the breakpoint that's for you to have debugging not required when done, what actual flow you need... explain that

Comment: I don't know what you're asking me, what I need is that the debug process stops before displaying the message(not black screen). Also, I don't unserstand the logCat's error above. Sorry if I'm not explaining the situation right, but I can't post a picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation is simple, but I don't know how to change this behavior:

When an Android app is running the main thread should process all incoming messages (from GUI and other internal messages). It is strictly forbidden to use the main thread for long lasting operations because in that time the thread is blocked and can not process messages.

When you start an app Android gives 10 seconds to the app to start-up. Afterwards it expects that the app is up for processing messages.

Now to your problem:

You have set a break-point in onCreate(..) a method that is called by the main thread - a thread that should not be blocked. Setting a break-point is nothing else that interrupting/blocking the thread until you press resume.
Hence after 10 seconds the Android system (which is not affected by your debugger) expects the app to be finished with starting-up. But the main thread is still trapped by the break-point! Therefore Android thinks that the app failed to start-up and stops certain part responsible for the GUI.

The only solution I see would be to disable this "Launch timeout" - however I don't have a clue if or how this is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. But I have a doubt. I tried this on my android phone and it stops perfectly(without black screen) as I said above. Why? What is the difference?

Comment: Returning to my problem, for example, I don't know if this happens always but if you create a graphic application, you need to see how the app progress to find bugs... So how can you debug it if the screen turns black?

Comment: @Robot, I have face same issue only on Mdpi tablets, I have use the xamarin and Mvvmcroos. the code is run fine on all the devices only shows black screen on Mdpi, so please give any solution, and in my code there is no any "Launch Timeout"